# How to clear custom slot value programmatically in Alexa?

Tags: javascript, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I have an Alexa skill which requires to programmatically override the values given by the user.

I have tried nullifying the value and later pass it in as the "updated Intent".

```
this.event.request.intent.userPrompt.value = null;
var updatedIntent = this.event.request.intent;
this.emit(':elicitSlot', 'userPrompt',"Say something","Say something", updatedIntent);
```

However, the input JSON shows previous value. Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is

```
delete this.event.request.intent.slots.<slotname>.value;
var updatedIntent = this event.request.intent;
this.emit(':elicitSlot', <slotname>,"Say something","Say something", updatedIntent);
```

if you have a slot with a custom slot type you also have to

```
delete this.event.request.intent.slots.<slotname>.resolutions;
```

Comment: Thanks @A.Kraus. This works as expected. You saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

For the version V2 you should update the intent in this way (as far as I know)

```
 handlerInput.responseBuilder
    .addDelegateDirective(newIntent)
    .getResponse();
```

`newIntent` should be an object where you can set your new slot values, for example :

```
const resetIntent = (handlerInput) => {
  const intent = {
    name : 'myIntentName',
    confirmationStatus: 'NONE',
    slots : {
      slotOne: {
        name: 'slotOne',
        confirmationStatus: 'NONE'
      }
    }
  }

  return handlerInput.responseBuilder
    .addDelegateDirective(intent)
    .getResponse();

}
```